# QTKit issue on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, qtkit

I'm having an issue with an existing QTKit codebase which I need to support for OSX Lion.
On upgrading to Lion our QT based capture (via QTCaptureSession) mostly seems to work fine.  However, on certain boxes, we get a crash as soon as QT is initialized.

The crash seems to be coming from a third party codec library (3ivx)

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                                      0x0ae64140 get_feature_flags + 0
1   lib3ivxEnc.dylib                         0x0ade1f3c InitHooks + 5088
2   lib3ivxEnc.dylib                         0x0ade3d52 InitThrivex + 68
3   lib3ivxEnc.dylib                         0x0adf7be0 l3_init + 11
4   com.3ivx.videocodec                      0x0ad7056d ThrivXCDOpen + 676
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore        0x90d0a86c callComponentStorage_44 + 25
6   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore        0x90db7aa1
```

We don't use this codec in our library, it just happens to be on the box.  Since the codec seems to be incompatible with OSX Lion I'd like to just prevent it from loading.

I haven't been able to find documentation on how to stop it from being loaded.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This crash is caused by ThrivXCDOpen component. Go to /System/Library/Quicktime and remove all 3ivx components you have got. You may need to reboot after.